# ¿Cómo tengo que acomodar el código para que funcione como quiero?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, sumatoria

Esta función es de una subasta que tiene un límite de tiempo cuando le faltan 5 minutos para acabar, entonces un postor hace una oferta y se agregan otros 5 minutos a la subasta, hasta que no haya más ofertas la subasta termina. entonces si me agrega los 5 minutos pero cada que se hace una oferta y lo que ocupo es que se sumen 5 minutos cuando oferten solamente cuando falten 5 minutos para que se terminen la subasta
Este es el código del tiempo entonces este código si funciona con la función que quiero, pero el único problema es que no se respetan las condiciones

```
<?php 


$secondsLimit=300;
$limitTime=$_POST["tiempo_limite"] ?? NULL;
if ($limitTime) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
    $currentDate = new \DateTime( "now");
    $endDate = new \DateTime($limitTime);
    # Calculamos el tiempo restante en segundos
    $secondsRemaining=$currentDate->getTimestamp()-$endDate->getTimestamp();
    $interval = $currentDate->diff($endDate);
    $outPut = sprintf("Fecha actual:\t %s%s",$currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
    $outPut .= sprintf("Fecha fin:\t %s%s",$endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
    if ($interval->format('%R') == '-' || $secondsRemaining===0) {
        $outPut .= "<b>Subasta cerrada</b>";
        ?>
        <script> document.getElementById('ofertar').disabled = true; </script>
      <?php
    } else {
       
        if ($secondsRemaining <= $secondsLimit) {
         
            $outPut.=sprintf('<p style="color:#FF4723">La subasta está por terminar. Termina en %s segundos',$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%S'));      
            if (isset($_POST['ofertar'])) {
                $minutesLimit=$secondsLimit/60;
                $endDate->add(new \DateInterval("PT{$minutesLimit}M"));
                $interval = $currentDate->diff($endDate);
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sNueva fecha fin: %s%s",PHP_EOL,$endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
                $outPut .= sprintf("%s<i class='icons icon-clock'></i> Tiempo restante: %s <br />",PHP_EOL,$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%S'));
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sSe realizó una nueva oferta en los últimos {$minutesLimit} minutos. La subasta se ha prolongado {$minutesLimit} minutos.",PHP_EOL);
               
            } else {
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo hubo nueva oferta",PHP_EOL);
            }                  
        } else {
            $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo se cumple la condición $secondsRemaining <= $secondsLimit",PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
} else {
    $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo se posteó un valor para tiempo_limite",PHP_EOL);
}
echo $outPut;


?>
```

***Este código es donde se agregan las ofertas y al momento de ofertar si se agregan los 5 minutos al tiempo final pero lo que ocupo es que se agreguen los 5 minutos solo cuando oferten faltando 5 minutos**

```
public function Registrar(){
            try{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO puja(Username, ID_Subasta, Valor, Fecha)
                                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())";
                $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $result = $stm->execute(array($this->getUsername(), $this->getIdsubasta(), 
                                              $this->getValor()));
                $stm->closeCursor(); //Cierra cursor MySQL
            
                    
            if ($result) {
                $currentEndTimeQuery="SELECT Tiempo_Fin FROM subasta WHERE ID_Subasta = ?;";
                $currentEndTimeStmt = $this->pdo->prepare($currentEndTimeQuery);
                $currentEndTimeStmt->execute([$this->getIdsubasta()]);
                $currentEndTime = $currentEndTimeStmt->fetchColumn();
            
                   $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($currentEndTime . '+ 5 minutes'));
                   $updateEndTimeQuery = "UPDATE subasta SET Tiempo_Fin = ? WHERE ID_Subasta = ?;";
                   $updateEndTimeStmt = $this->pdo->prepare($updateEndTimeQuery);
                   $updateEndTimeStmt->execute([$endDate, $this->getIdsubasta()]);

                   $currentEndTimeStmt->closeCursor();
                   $updateEndTimeStmt->closeCursor();
            }
                return $result;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $_SESSION['msgError1'] = 'Error al guardar: '.$e->getMessage();
            }

        }
```

como le podría hacer ya funciona solo se que tengo mal algo pero no logro descubrir en resumen **si agrega los 5 minutos ala hora de ofertar pero yo ocupo que se agreguen 5 minutos cuando oferten en los últimos 5 minutos**

Comment: **@todos** ayuda

Comment: dame 5 minutos ya casi termino la propuesta.... a ver si lo solucionamos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agreguen los 5 minutos adicionales solo cuando se oferte en los últimos 5 minutos, debes realizar los siguientes cambios en tu código:

1. Modifica la función `Registrar()` para que primero verifique si la oferta se realiza en los últimos 5 minutos antes de agregar los minutos adicionales. Puedes hacer esto obteniendo el tiempo restante y comparándolo con el límite de 5 minutos:

```
public function Registrar(){
    try{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO puja(Username, ID_Subasta, Valor, Fecha)
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())";
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stm->execute(array($this->getUsername(), $this->getIdsubasta(), $this->getValor()));
        $stm->closeCursor(); //Cierra cursor MySQL

        if ($result) {
            $currentEndTimeQuery = "SELECT Tiempo_Fin FROM subasta WHERE ID_Subasta = ?;";
            $currentEndTimeStmt = $this->pdo->prepare($currentEndTimeQuery);
            $currentEndTimeStmt->execute([$this->getIdsubasta()]);
            $currentEndTime = $currentEndTimeStmt->fetchColumn();

            date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
            $currentDate = new DateTime("now");
            $endDate = new DateTime($currentEndTime);

            // Calcula el tiempo restante en segundos
            $secondsRemaining = $endDate->getTimestamp() - $currentDate->getTimestamp();

            if ($secondsRemaining <= 300) { // Verifica si quedan 5 minutos o menos
                $endDate->add(new DateInterval("PT5M")); // Agrega 5 minutos adicionales
                $newEndTime = $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $updateEndTimeQuery = "UPDATE subasta SET Tiempo_Fin = ? WHERE ID_Subasta = ?;";
                $updateEndTimeStmt = $this->pdo->prepare($updateEndTimeQuery);
                $updateEndTimeStmt->execute([$newEndTime, $this->getIdsubasta()]);

                $currentEndTimeStmt->closeCursor();
                $updateEndTimeStmt->closeCursor();
            }
        }

        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $_SESSION['msgError1'] = 'Error al guardar: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

2. En el código que muestra el tiempo restante y las condiciones, también debes tener en cuenta el nuevo comportamiento al verificar si se agregaron los 5 minutos adicionales:

```
if ($interval->format('%R') == '-' || $secondsRemaining === 0) {
    $outPut .= "<b>Subasta cerrada</b>";
    ?>
    <script> document.getElementById('ofertar').disabled = true; </script>
  <?php
} else {
    if ($secondsRemaining <= $secondsLimit) {
        $outPut .= sprintf('<p style="color:#FF4723">La subasta está por terminar. Termina en %s segundos', $interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%S'));
        if (isset($_POST['ofertar'])) {
            if ($secondsRemaining <= 300) { // Verifica si quedan 5 minutos o menos
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sSe realizó una nueva oferta en los últimos 5 minutos. La subasta se ha prolongado 5 minutos.", PHP_EOL);
            } else {
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sSe realizó una nueva oferta.", PHP_EOL);
            }
        } else {
            $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo hubo nueva oferta", PHP_EOL);
        }
    } else {
        $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo se cumple la condición $secondsRemaining <= $secondsLimit", PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

Entonces ... el tiempo restante se verifica tanto para determinar si la subasta ha finalizado como para agregar los 5 minutos adicionales solo cuando se oferte en los últimos 5 minutos. Asegúrate de tener en cuenta **el ajuste de la zona horaria** adecuada en la función *[date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)* según tu ubicación.

Los ejemplo que te he dado son As-is no he tenido tiempo de verificar 100% su funcionamiento o eficacia. debes hacer tus propias adaptaciones adicionales según tus necesidades y estructura de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias encerio llevaba como dos semanas atorado en esto gracias **@ArcanisGK507**